# Entity Framework, EntityCommandExecutionExeption

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Using Simple Membership provider.... and a User view ( that passes UserID into ) Userroles Controller

My Index ( of UserRoles ) ( the ID is UserID from ActionLink in the View from User Controller)

```
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "id")] int id)
    {
        var usr = db.UserRoles.Find(id);

        if (usr != null)
        {
            return View(usr);
        }

        return View();
        //return View(db.UserRoles.ToList());
    }
```

But my model is

```
[Table("webpages_UsersInRoles")]
public class UserRoles
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

}
```

Error 
[image]

Thanks

In other words, It shouldnt even be lookingfor UserProfiles_UserID.....?

Also i do get this : 
Stack Trace:

```
 [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'UserProfiles_UserId'.
 Invalid column name 'UserProfiles_UserId'.
```

Nor my Database or my Model have this field in it ;/ im confused on why its looking for it?

Comment: Your title makes no sense

Comment: the title is supposed to say, what i have issues with right? ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a user to a role with the following code:

```
 System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUsersToRole("user1", "user2", "user3", ... , "yourrolename");
```